# Silent installation for Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 in powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, imagemagick

I want to do following installation silently in server 2008 R2 using powershell. Can you please help me to solve this issue? I am using below command but it's not working.

```
start -FilePath "$scriptLocation\Prerequisites\vcredist_x64.exe" -ArgumentList "-standalone /qb" -Verb RunAs
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the value for $scriptLocation is correct, I suspect the issue may be with the arguments list. Try this.

```
start-process -FilePath "$scriptLocation\Prerequisites\vcredist_x64.exe" -ArgumentList "/install /quiet" -Verb RunAs
```